# How to configure pre loader in Webpack 2.1.0 beta 23

Tags: webpack

Having just upgraded Webpack to 2.1.0 beta 25 I have been unable to find any guidance on how to configure pre loaders. The beta 23 release notes mention the depreciation of preloaders but the explanation of the replacement functionality leaves me a little lost. Where do I configure the enforcement?

> removed postLoaders and preLoaders
>
> rules enforce: "left" and enforce: "right" can be used instead.

My use case is just running the eslint loader before the .js transpilation step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `left` and `right` were too confusing, if you look at v2.1.0-beta.24 they've now renamed it to `pre` and `post`, which make a lot more sense. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta.24

An example of what would have been an ESLint `preLoader` in the past:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'eslint',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      enforce: 'pre'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ah hah! I totally missed that in the release notes 

Comment: So did I. Took a good while to track down. :)

I think they could do a much better job of keeping docs up to date with releases, it seems to be something that's on the way though.